# Asymptotic behavior of functions

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I want to compare this two functions, $f(n) = n \log(n)$ and $g(n) = 2^{\log(n)^2}$. I have the strong intuition that $f(n)$ is $o(g(n))$ but I have had some problems solving formally this. Do you have a hint to attack this problem?

I have tried to use the bound of $\log$ to try to under bound the limit but has not work.

Comment: A useful lemma in this topic, for functions $f,g$ tending to $\infty$, is: if $\log f(n) = o(\log g(n))$ then $f(n) = o(g(n))$. (Note that many variations of this lemma are false, so be careful.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** write both as
$$2^{a(n)}$$
and compare the exponents. Note that your $g$ is already in this form.